# Clubbing 2 ggplots in a single windows and putting 2nd one in Secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have 2 `ggplots`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
set.seed(1)
data = structure(list(fecha = structure(c(1317452400, 1317538800, 1317625200, 
1317711600, 1317798000, 1317884400, 1317970800, 1318057200, 1318143600, 
1318230000, 1318316400, 1318402800, 1318489200, 1318575600, 1318662000, 
1318748400, 1318834800, 1318921200, 1319007600, 1319094000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TempMax = c(26.58, 27.78, 27.9, 27.44, 
30.9, 30.44, 27.57, 25.71, 25.98, 26.84, 33.58, 30.7, 31.3, 27.18, 
26.58, 26.18, 25.19, 24.19, 27.65, 23.92), TempMedia = c(22.88, 
22.87, 22.41, 21.63, 22.43, 22.29, 21.89, 20.52, 19.71, 20.73, 
23.51, 23.13, 22.95, 21.95, 21.91, 20.72, 20.45, 19.42, 19.97, 
19.61), TempMin = c(19.34, 19.14, 18.34, 17.49, 16.75, 16.75, 
16.88, 16.82, 14.82, 16.01, 16.88, 17.55, 16.75, 17.22, 19.01, 
16.95, 17.55, 15.21, 14.22, 16.42)), .Names = c("fecha", "TempMax", 
"TempMedia", "TempMin"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
data['val'] = rnorm(dim(data)[1], 10000, 1)
data

mycolor = c('red', 'green'); names(mycolor) = c('TempMax', 'TempMedia')
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = fecha)) +
        geom_line(aes(y = TempMax, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = TempMedia, colour = 'TempMedia'), size = 1.2) +
        scale_colour_manual('color', breaks = names(mycolor), values = mycolor)

p2 = ggplot(data, aes(x = fecha)) +
        geom_bar(aes(y = val), stat = "identity", color = 'grey')
```

The individual plots for `p1` and `p2` are perfect, however I want to club them in a single plot window with `p2` as `secondary axis`. I took some reference from [ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales), and tried to implement that with below code

```
ggdraw(insert_yaxis_grob(p1, get_y_axis(p2, position='right')))
```

But it does not seem to be working. Could you please help to understand the right method, given that data for `p2` is not any transformation of the date for `p1`.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the values you wish to plot on the y axis into approximately the same scale as the existing values, then draw a second axis using `sec_axis` inside the call `scale_y_continuous` which reverses that transformation. In your case, subtracting 9997 from `var` and multiplying it by 6 puts it into a reasonable range (between 5 and 30). The secondary axis labels therefore need divided by 6 then added to 9997:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = fecha)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (val - 9997) * 6, fill = 'val')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = TempMax, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = TempMedia, colour = 'TempMedia'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_colour_manual('color', breaks = names(mycolor), values = mycolor) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = 'deepskyblue3') +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp',
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x / 6 + 9997), name = 'var'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to control the `range` of the secondary axis and `tick labels` as well? I also want to remove the reference of `val` from legend. Is that possible?

Comment: You can make the range of the  secondary axis anything you like by changing the transformation. You can change the breaks and tick labels to anything you want using the `breaks` and `labels` arguments of `sec_axis`.  You can remove the name either by setting `name = ""` or removing it inside `theme` with `axis.title.y.right = element_blank()`