# Strange behaviour when I add secondary axis in my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is one application from my earlier post on similar subject - [Clubbing 2 ggplots in a single windows and putting 2nd one in Secondary axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604839/clubbing-2-ggplots-in-a-single-windows-and-putting-2nd-one-in-secondary-axis/71605123?noredirect=1#comment126555687_71605123)

Let say I have below `ggplot`, and I want to have secondary axis for the variable `y2`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
dat = data.frame(x = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2002-01-01'), length.out = 17, by = '95 day')),
                    y1 = c(-0.0042, 0.0221, 0.0387, 0.0523, -0.0743, -0.0903, 0.0997, 0.0982, 0.0956, -0.0961, -0.0696, -0.0818, 0.0766, 0.0654, 0.1275, 0.1178, 0.0878),
                    y2 = c(19747, 19343, 19007, 18336, 17534, 16548, 15536, 14400, 13428, 12686, 11877, 11250, 10625, 10122, 9740, 9314, 8892))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (y2 - 14000) / 8000), fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp', limits = c(-3, 3),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000 + 14000), name = 'var'))
```

With this I am getting below plot

[image]

This plot looks strange to me. Why my bars for `y2` going to negative territory?

I also tried with changing the transformation as,

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (y2 - 8000) / 8000), fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp', limits = c(-3, 3),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000 + 8000), name = 'var'))
```

With this, I get below plot

[image]

As you see, the range for `secondary y axis` still going into negative zone. I would ideally expect to see limit of `secondary y axis` starting from 0. Any idea on how can I make this correction will be very helpful.

Comment: `sec_axis` is a red-herring, the plot looks identical with that portion removed from your code (except for the second axis, of course, which does nothing to the main plot elements/layers).

Comment: Your bars go negative because `range(dat$y2 - 14000) / 8000` returns `-0.638500  0.718375`. Is your hard-coded `14000` (and possibly `8000`) supposed to be something else?

Comment: I wanted to approximately match the transformed range of `y2` to that of `y1`. But why that should matter? I am again transforming back with `~(.x * 8000 + 14000)`. Should not it negate my earlier transformation? What is the correct rule? I basically want to automate this transformation so that `y1` and `y2` can co-exist with `y2` in secondary axis

Comment: Have a look at your y2. Starting from the 9th element, your red bars become negative (when compared to the left y axis). Your 9th element from y2 is 13428. In your geom_col you re-calculate the value `y2 - 14000) / 8000`, which for 13428 is equal to -0,0715, a negative value (on the left y axis). 
You then recalculate your second y axis as .x * 8000 + 14000, which for 0 (on the first y axis) equals to 0 * 8000 + 14000 = 14000 on your second y axis. 
The calculation you did was right, and the 9th value from y2 (13428) is indeed 13428 when read according to your second y axis.

Comment: @Gnueghoidune I changed the transformation to `(y2 - 8000) / 8000)`. With this, I get the range of `right y axis` starting from negative value, while the plot appears to be okay. Is there any way to force the starting value of `secondary y axis` from 0? I modified my original post with this information

Comment: remove the addition/subtraction and stick to division/multiplication only.

Comment: If I do `geom_col(aes(y = (y2 - 0) / 8000), fill = 'red')` and `sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000 + 0)` I still get the range of `secondary y axis` in negative territory

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust/manipulate/force the `sec.axis` to start at `0` you can use `expand = c(-3, 3)`

Sample code:

```
   library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (y2 - 14000) / 8000), fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp', 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000 + 14000), name = 'var'), expand = c(-3, 3))
```

Plot:

[image]

With regards to your remark - standalone basis of the `sec.axis`

with `expand =c (-3,3)`

[image]

and with `limits=c(-3,3)`

[image]

For the second code, I would use `expand=c(0,1)`

[image]

You could scale the `x axis` as well

Sample code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (y2 - 8000) / 8000), fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp', expand = c(0, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000 + 8000), name = 'var'))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme_bw()
```

Plot:

[image]
Sample data:

```
dat = data.frame(x = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2002-01-01'), length.out = 17, by = '95 day')),
                 y1 = c(-0.0042, 0.0221, 0.0387, 0.0523, -0.0743, -0.0903, 0.0997, 0.0982, 0.0956, -0.0961, -0.0696, -0.0818, 0.0766, 0.0654, 0.1275, 0.1178, 0.0878),
                 y2 = c(19747, 19343, 19007, 18336, 17534, 16548, 15536, 14400, 13428, 12686, 11877, 11250, 10625, 10122, 9740, 9314, 8892))
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont think if I plot `y2` standalone basis, I would get similar plot like yours

Comment: Thanks for edits. But if you please look at the 2nd plot in my original post, you can see that the plot for `y2` is different (sort of descending), but in your plot it is different.

Comment: @Brian Smith sorry I just observed it!

Comment: Nps. I just want that in my 2nd plot, the `secondary y axis` should start from 0. I am clueless why this axis is taking negative values where no values for `y2` is negative

Comment: Your current plot is almost perfect, except that the bar plots looks kike floating in vaccum (like mine), is it possible to anchor them at 0 in `secondary y axis`?

Answer (score 0):

Would this suit your needs?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (y2 / 8000), fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = 'TempMax'), size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Temp', limits = c(-0.2, 3),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.x * 8000), name = 'var'))
```

[image]